# VBA Access SQL Server table insert

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have some problem when I deal with MS Access. I am using SQL Server and MS Access together.

I try to insert data into a new table.

First, this program asks me to add an item to the list (it is like temporary table). And then, there is another submit button which confirms the data (this step is needed and it is not inefficient one. Please do not ask about this step).

To add data to the list, I use a stored procedure. But I do not know what do I need to do to submit the data again.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Insert into dbo.Blend values(List731.Column(1, introw),List731.Column(2, introw),TextRequestNo.Value, List731.Column(3, introw),List731.Column(4, introw),List731.Column(5, introw))"
conn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
MsgBox "Done"
```

When I run with this code, I get this error:

[image]

I think there is some missing in my code but I do not know how to proceed.
Is there anyone who can give me some information about this?

Comment: recordsets are for selecting data, not inserting. https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=219149 has an example how to do an insert (and do it more cleanly using parameters). Or you could even do `conn.Execute` as well, although I don't know if you can use parameters that way. The other possibility is simply that you didn't connect to the server correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this kind of thing.  Something like this should get the job done.

```
Sub MoveDateFromAccessToSQLServer()

Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConnString As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=servername;Database=NORTHWIND;User Id=xx;Password=password"

Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'adoCN.Open sConnString

'Assumes that you have Field1, Field2 and Field3 in columns A, B and C
'Text values must be enclosed in apostrophes whereas numeric values should not.



    sSQL = "INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) " & _
            " VALUES (" & _
            "'" & Column(1, introw) & "', " & _
            "'" & Column(2, introw) & "', " & _
            "'" & Column(3, introw) & "')"

    adoCN.Execute sSQL



adoCN.Close

Set adoCN = Nothing


End Sub
```